# Copying attribute values to new layer in QGIS with python

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, pyqgis-3

I am making a buffer for a point layer and want the attribute values to be copied over to the new layer. I am able to duplicate the attribute fields, but not populate them with the values. I get the error 
*AttributeError: 'QgsVectorDataProvider' object has no attribute 'setAttributes'*

```
lyr = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('lyr')[0]
iface.setActiveLayer(lyr)
lyr = iface.activeLayer()

#set var
width=30

buffLyr = QgsVectorLayer('Polygon?crs=EPSG:3857', ' Buffer', 'memory')
pr= buffLyr.dataProvider()

#duplicate the field from the original layer and update fields
pr.addAttributes(lyr.fields())
buffLyr.updateFields()

#apply buffer to each feature
for selection in lyr.getFeatures():
    buff = selection.geometry().buffer(width_m,6)

    #Add feature attribute values
    attrs =selection.attributes()
    pr.setAttributes(attrs)


    #Create a new feature:
    b = QgsFeature()
    b.setGeometry(buff)

    #Add the feature to the data provider:
    pr.addFeatures([b])

    buffLyr.updateExtents()

QgsProject.instance().addMapLayers([buffLyr])
```

Comment: **setAttributes** applies to _Qgsfeature_ not _QgsDataProvider_ (it seems ...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove `pr.setAttributes(attrs)` line and add after `b.setGeometry(buff)` the line `b.setAttributes(attrs)`

You can replace your code alternatively with call to existing processing script for buffer e.g

```py
from qgis import processing

myresult = processing.run("native:buffer", {'INPUT': '/home/user/input.shp',
              'DISTANCE': 100.0,
              'SEGMENTS': 10,
              'DISSOLVE': False,
              'END_CAP_STYLE': 0,
              'JOIN_STYLE': 0,
              'MITER_LIMIT': 10,
              'OUTPUT': '/home/user/output_buffers.shp'})

iface.addVectorLayer(myresult['OUTPUT'], "Buffer", "ogr")
```

Credits mostly to the official documentation https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/loadlayer.html
You should read the doc from this link to understand how to reuse other existing scripts from processing toolbox.